# Неправильный конструктор копирования

Tags: c++

В следующем фрагменте кода:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Point
{
    int x;

public:
    Point(int x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }

    Point(Point p)
    {
        x = p.x;
    }

    int getX() { return x; }
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    Point p1(10);
    Point p2 = p1;

    printf("%d", p2.getX());
    return 0;
}
```

Компилятор выдает такую ошибку:

```
invalid constructor; you probably meant 'Point (const Point&)
```

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

В *C++* *конструктор копирования* не может принимать *копию объекта* этого же класса, а вот по ссылке может (т.е. в вашем случае подойдет `Point(Point& p)`, либо `Point(const Point& p)`).

---

**Представим, что такое допустимо**

Получается, что таким образом вы переопределяете *конструктор копирования по умолчанию*, тогда у компилятора не остается выбора (на самом деле просто запрещен такой вызов, но так звучит убедительнее) кроме как попытаться снова вызвать именно ваш *конструктор копирования* для передачи параметра в ваш же *конструктор копирования* и так далее (бесконечная рекурсия получается).

Comment: а я и не хочу переопределять конструктор копирования, я хочу переопределить конструктор инициализации. Да, ето не ефективно, но почему ошыбка?

Comment: @VladD я знаю как происходит передача параметров по значению. Визывается конструктор копирования. "Потому что то, что вы написали, для передачи параметра в конструктор копирования требует конструктор копирования" - пусть и требует , визивется  конструктор копирования по умолчанию  , но почему ошибка?

Comment: @StateItPrimitive написал 4-й коментарий, думаю ясно виразился

Comment: @StateItPrimitive ето нужно добавить в ответ

Answer (score 3):

Потому что копирующий конструктор должен иметь одну из стандартных форм:

```
Point(const          Point & copy);
Point(               Point & copy);
Point(const volatile Point & copy);
Point(      volatile Point & copy);
```

Comment: @Abyx, это Вы про параметры по умолчанию? Полагаю, ими можно пренебречь в данном вопросе.

Comment: @ixSci Изначально ответ имел несколько другой вид просто :)